# how can I deserialize a non unified json in Java?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I want to send the server an http request with this json (upper line)

and I want to get such a json and parse it to Java object (lower line)

[image]

I remember from last times, that a missing field in a collection that I want to deserialize

crashes the deserialization

(for a single deserialization, if the json has no such field - a default value is inserted)

Is there any way I can create a single Java class to represent both the request json and the two types on response json objects?

My try:

```
public class ConfigValue {

    public String key;
    public String defaultValue;
    public String value;
}




Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Array<ConfigValue>>() {
                        }.getType();

                        ConfigValue[] configValues = (ConfigValue[]) gson
                                            .fromJson(result, collectionType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the two JSON strings in your image are directly a list (or array) of ConfigValue objects. They are in fact a JSON object, with one property `configValues`, which is a list of ConfigValue objects. You therefore need a wrapper class to deserialize them to:

```
public class ConfigValues {
    public ConfigValue[] configValues;
}

public class ConfigValue {
    public String key;
    public String defaultValue;
    public String value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstJson = "{\"configValues\":[{\"key\":\"radiusMeters\",\"value\":\"200\"}]}";
    String secondJson = "{\"configValues\":[{\"key\":\"redeemExpirationMins\",\"defaultValue\":\"300\"},{\"key\":\"radiusMeters\",\"value\":\"200\",\"defaultValue\":\"400\"}]}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    
    ConfigValues firstConfigValues = gson.fromJson(firstJson, ConfigValues.class);
    ConfigValues secondConfigValues = gson.fromJson(secondJson, ConfigValues.class);
    
    System.out.println(firstConfigValues);
    System.out.println(secondConfigValues);
}
```

If you add toString methods to the two classes, the main method prints the following deserialized objects:

> ConfigValues(configValues=[ConfigValue(key=radiusMeters, defaultValue=null, value=200)])
>
> ConfigValues(configValues=[ConfigValue(key=redeemExpirationMins, defaultValue=300, value=null), ConfigValue(key=radiusMeters, defaultValue=400, value=200)])

You can see that any missing fields of ConfigValue are deserialized to null.

Comment: yes, when deserializing a single object the default is assigned to non existing in json fields. When I convert a whole collection (as my code above) it just fails. how come?